# Inserting a node in LinkedList is giving segmentation error

Tags: c++, data-structures, while-loop, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
struct Node
{
   int data;
   Node * next;
   Node (int x)
   {
     data=x;
     next=NULL;
   }     
};

Node * insertInSorted(Node * head, int data)
{
    Node* temp = new Node(data);

    if (head == NULL){
       return temp;
    }

   if (data < head->data){
    temp->next = head
    return temp;
   }
    
    Node* curr = head;
    
    while (curr->next->data < data && curr->next != NULL){
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    temp->next = curr->next;
    curr->next = temp;
    return head;
}
```

Hi, I've recently learned C++ and have been practicing LinkedList, this question is simple all I've to do is insert an element at its correct position while maintaining the sorted order.
My question is why am I getting segmentation fault. I noticed that in the while loop if I flip the order from ***while (curr->next->data < data && curr->next != NULL)*** to ***while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->data < data)*** segmentation error does not occur. Can someone please help me understand this problem?

Comment: `&&` evaluates the left-hand expression first, which will segfault if `curr->next` is null, without performing the right-hand chack

Comment: is there a way to override this short-circuiting behavior?

Comment: @EklavyaShukla no, so change the code to utilize it the right way - check for NULL first, not second: `while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->data < data)`

Comment: "I've recently learned C++" no, it would be more correct to say that you just recently started the process of learning C++.  Did you already know C, or is this mostly C style with a dash of C++ (no need for `struct` before the type name, using `new` instead of `malloc`) the way you are being taught?

Comment: Once the code _works_, you can try posting it on the [Code Reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack for some critical feedback.

Comment: I know a little bit of C, learned it in school. But this code is completely c++. In C to use the struct by directly writing the name of struct, I'd have to add an indef keyword right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This while loop

```
while (curr->next->data < data && curr->next != NULL){
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

can invoke undefined behavior because there is no check whether `curr->next` is equal to `nullptr` before accessing the data member `curr->next->data`. You need to exchange the operands of the logical AND operator like

```
while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->data < data ){
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

In any case the function can be written without checks of numerous conditions the following way if to use pointer to pointer.

```
Node * insertInSorted( Node *head, int data )
{
    Node *temp = new Node( data );

    Node **current = &head;

    while ( *current && !( data < ( *current )->data ) )
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    temp->next = *current;
    *current = temp;

    return head;
}
```

Pay attention to that you could pass the pointer to the head node to the function by reference. In this case there is no need to return the pointer to the head node from the function. The user of the original function can forget to assign the returned pointer from the function to the pointer within the caller of the function.

So a more safer function definition can look the following way

```
void insertInSorted( Node * &head, int data )
{
    Node *temp = new Node( data );

    Node **current = &head;

    while ( *current && !( data < ( *current )->data ) )
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    temp->next = *current;
    *current = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing such a good explanation and also for telling me extra ways to re-write this function.

Answer (score 3):

The way you wrote it, this:

```
curr->next->data < data
```

is evaluated before this:

```
curr->next != NULL
```

Therefore, `curr->next` can be NULL when you try to dereference it in `curr->next->data`, so you access some random part of memory and you get a segmentation fault.

As you said, changing the order fixes it, and that is the correct solution. When the first part of an `AND` expression is false, the second part is not evaluated, so you won't try to dereference an invalid address, so your problem is fixed.

Comment: thank you your explanation was crisp and to the point, it helped me clear the question.